# Haskell No instance arising from a use of 'print'

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function toTree that converts a list of values to a binary tree:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
tree = Branch 6 (Branch 3 Leaf Leaf) (Branch 9 Leaf Leaf)

split :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
split lst = splitAt (((length lst) + 1) `div` 2) lst
toTree :: [a] -> Tree a
toTree (x: xs) = Branch x (toTree xm) (toTree xl) where (xm, xl) = split xs
toTree [] = Leaf
```

I cannot figure why I get this error on `toTree [1,2,3]`

```
 No instance for (Show (Tree a0)) arising from a use of `print'
 In the first argument of `print', namely `it'
 In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I know this  is a simple error to fix but I cannot seem to find what is causing it. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just add

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
            deriving Show
```

the error just says that Haskell does not know how to *show* a value of type `Tree a0` (`print` is using `show` from the `Show` type-class)

And the easiest way is to auto-derive it

Or you have to implement it yourself using something like this:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Tree a) where
  show Leaf = "leaf"
  show (Branch v l r) = "(left: " ++ show l ++ ") " ++ show v ++ " (right: " ++ show r ++ ")"
```

where I just made something up to give you something like this:

```
λ> toTree [1,2,3]
(left: (left: leaf) 2 (right: leaf)) 1 (right: (left: leaf) 3 (right: leaf))
```

Comment: Ok thanks for helping me out. I'm still new to the language.

Comment: no problem - keep going it's worth it - btw: this is such a minor detail - the rest of your code is working after all ;)

Comment: how can I print a `Leaf` alone?

Comment: @zhirzh you mean you want to see only the values of the leaves? - Just change the `show (Branch v l r)` case accordingly